# How to change file path in python

Tags: python, file-io

How would I edit the path of a file I created with file.open in python? For example, with my code:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
GENPASS = ["g","q"]
FILENAME = "Test.txt"
ACC = "Test"
FILE = open(FILENAME,'a')
FILE.write(ACC)
FILE.write(','.join(GENPASS)+"/n")
```

How would I change the path of "FILE"

Comment: The title is supposed to be "How to change file path in python"

Comment: Please precise your problem and define expected output for given input.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `FILE.write(.join(GENPASS)+"/n")` doesn't look like valid syntax to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the path of `FILE` you will have to set it up in this declaration:

e.g.

```
FILENAME = "/mypath/Test.txt"
```